# ATI drivers: delay when unminimizing

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx

I installed the proprietary ATI/AMD FGLRX graphics driver through "jockey-gtk" to get rid of my computer's over heating problems. While my computer no longer overheats, I am stuck with a new problem:

When I click on a minimized application in the task bar in order to restore it (unminimize it), there is always a short delay of about 1 second.

Any suggestion on how to approach this problem? 1 second might not seem so bad but for a power user it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by following the steps mentioned in this [blog post](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/05/how-to-fix-maximize-delaylag-with.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:info-g-com/xserver-xorg-1.7.6-gc;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get upgrade;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Free ATi driver - there's a bit of a delay with the "magic lamp" animations. You can disable these with Compiz Config Settings Manager in Universe.